# Laravel blade template name from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a master blade file which will include another blade file based on a DB value like so:

```
@include('sign/templates/{{$SignRequest->form_template}}')
```

The db field form_template contains the name of the blade file to include. This name is passed to the master blade file correctly, but I can't figure out how to use this value within the include statement.

I get the following error:

```
View [sign.templates.<?php echo e($SignRequest->form_template); ?>] not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@include('sign.templates.'.$SignRequest->form_template)
```